# MS Access front-end cannot modify records when connected to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ms-access

I migrated my Access tables to MySQL hosted server and linked the tables back to MS Access front-end and now I cannot edit the records in my forms. I can see the data and go between records, but I cannot edit data at all. Cannot select other values from drop down, or even modify a misspelling. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors at all.

Comment: Can you use a tool like MySQL Workbench? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thanks. I have used MySQL Workbench, but I don't what I should do there to fix my problem. Can you advise what I should do?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-apptips-microsoft.html) and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access.html. Provide necessary infos (odbc connection config, version infos for db and connector, office version) User has sufficent priviliges to edit data (try in workbench from same client)

Comment: @Alex I know this is an old question, but did you happen to figure out what the problem was?